# Is it possible to save the save figure in different ranges, without plotting it twice?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have one data set which is very big, **it takes a long time to plot**. I want to save two figures of it in different range. In the GUI, I just plot once and zoom in to the desired range, and repeat to get the other range. How to do it in automatically the code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)



# Create the first figure
plt.figure("fig1")

plt.scatter(x, y)  # suppose plot this will take a long time

plt.ylim(-1, 0)
plt.title("Figure 1: Sin(x) with y-range (-1, 0)")

# Save the first figure
plt.savefig("figure1.png")

# Create the second figure
plt.figure("fig2")

plt.scatter(x, y)  # is it possible to avoid this second plot? 

plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.title("Figure 2: Sin(x) with y-range (0, 1)")

# Save the second figure
plt.savefig("figure2.png")

# Show the plots
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot` by default saves previously plotted data, so you do not need to replot or re-create the figure

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)



# Create the first figure
plt.figure("fig1")

plt.scatter(x, y)  # suppose plot this will take a long time

plt.ylim(-1, 0)
plt.title("Figure 1: Sin(x) with y-range (-1, 0)")

# Save the first figure
plt.savefig("figure1.png")

plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.title("Figure 2: Sin(x) with y-range (0, 1)")

# Save the second figure
plt.savefig("figure2.png")

# Show the plots
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible to pop up two figures (not saving them), with only one plt.plot?